# How to fix controller error in Ruby on Rails and get Paperclip up and running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying for quite a while to get Paperclip up and running on my website and have followed the step-by-step process outlined on github *multiple* times and it still won't work. I really need to get this up and running as soon as possible. When I run the code through localhost, I get the message "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass." This is located in line 20 (commented below). Why doesn't it appear as an error for the identical line under the owners method?

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @survey = Survey.new
    end

    def create
    end

    def survey_params
        params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :email, :password)
    end

    def owners
        @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
        @survey.user_id=current_user.id
        @survey.save
    end

    def seeker
        @survey = Survey.new
        @survey.user_id=current_user.id   # line with the error (line 20)
        @survey.save
    end

    private

        def survey_params
            params.require(:survey).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :looking_for, :moving_to, :gender, :coed, :age, :roommate_type, :housing_type, :roommates_estimate, :roommates_amount, :roommates_group, :roommates_names, :max_rent, :move_in, :move_out, :bedrooms, :amenities, :apartment_pet, :roommate_pet, :hometown, :school, :company, :terms, :avatar, :wake_up, :bedtime, :smoke, :smokeoften, :smokesocially, :smokequit, :drink, :drinkoften, :drinksocially, :drinkquit, :drugs, :drugsoften, :drugssocially, :drugsquit, :interest, :sexualactivity, :sexprivacy, :roommatesexprivacy, :overnight, :overnightoften, :roommateovernight, :realty, :availability, :rent, :address, :otherroom, :age_min, :age_max, :age_mode, :pad_photo, :user_status, :sociability, :tidiness, :question, :noise, :political, :religion, :user_id)
        end

        def idcheck
        end
end
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get Paperclip up and running? I would really appreciate any kind of assistance I can get with this because I have a pretty close deadline.

Comment: seems like current_user is nil in this case.  Do you have a current_user logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting `current_user`?

Generally this is set via a "sign_in" method or some such, eg:

**app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    # "permanent" = expires: 20.years.from_now.utc
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    return unless cookies[:remember_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

Your specific methods likely vary, but that general pattern is often assumed to be in place in your project. Wherever you handle login flow, the current user should be set to some variable that you can refer to via your controllers. You need to make sure you're setting and using that variable.

Additionally, you should have a `before_filter` in the controller to ensure only logged-in users can access these actions.

Comment: OK, thank you. I made those changes, but still have an error. It's saying "param is missing or the value is empty: survey" as well as: "app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:11:in `survey_params'
app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:15:in `owners'" Where do I set this? What's going on?

Comment: Two notes: {1} you're defining `survey_params` twice (and differently), so that's bad, and {2} it sounds like your params hash does not contain a `:survey` key. You should log the params to investigate further.

Comment: Also, at this point, you should probably resolve this ticket, and after you've done some more investigation, potentially file a new one with your cleaned up code (eg no duplicate method, additional detail after current investigation, etc) -- if you stick with this ticket then you'll likely get fewer eyes due to topic drift etc.

Answer (score 0):

do you also use Devise?

if yes,

please add

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:seeker]
```

after

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
```

then Devise will ask you login before you do the seeker action.

If you don't use devise, would you mind post your Gemfile or let me know where did you get this current_suer